# Необъявленные теги

Tags: java, android, криптография

Имею такой код из примера библиотеки Spongy Castle. Компилятор ругается на `oTAG`, `ouTAG`, `lTAG` Объясните что это за теги такие и как из объявить?

```
X500NameBuilder nameBuilder = new X500NameBuilder(BCStyle.INSTANCE);
nameBuilder.addRDN(BCStyle.O,oTAG);
nameBuilder.addRDN(BCStyle.OU,ouTAG);
nameBuilder.addRDN(BCStyle.L,lTAG);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эти теги образуют [RDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) (Relative Distinguished Name). В этом примере, это просто строковые переменные:

- oTAG - Organization
- ouTAG - Organization Unit
- lTAG - Locality

Например

```
String ouTAG = "Hive";
String oTAG = "Umbrella Corp.";
String lTAG = "Raccoon";
```